# Таймер обратного отсчета по суткам

Tags: таймер, javascript

День добрый.

Есть такой код

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    function CountdownTimer(elm, tl, mes) {
        this.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
    }
    CountdownTimer.prototype = {
        initialize: function (elm, tl, mes) {
            this.elem = document.getElementById(elm);
            this.tl = tl;
            this.mes = mes;
        },
        countDown: function () {
            var timer = '';
            //  var today=new Date();
            var today = (new Date()).getTime() + 60 * 1000;
            var day = Math.floor((this.tl - today) / (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
            var hour = Math.floor(((this.tl - today) % (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)) / (60 * 60 * 1000));
            var min = Math.floor(((this.tl - today) % (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)) / (60 * 1000)) % 60;
            var sec = Math.floor(((this.tl - today) % (24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)) / 1000) % 60 % 60;
            var me = this;

            if ((this.tl - today) > 0) {
                timer += '<span class="number-wrapper"><div class="line"></div><div class="caption">Дни</div><span class="number day">' + day + '</span></span>';
                timer += '<span class="number-wrapper"><div class="line"></div><div class="caption">Часы</div><span class="number hour">' + hour + '</span></span>';
                timer += '<span class="number-wrapper"><div class="line"></div><div class="caption">Минуты</div><span class="number min">' + this.addZero(min) + '</span></span><span class="number-wrapper"><div class="line"></div><div class="caption">Секунды</div><span class="number sec">' + this.addZero(sec) + '</span></span>';
                this.elem.innerHTML = timer;
                tid = setTimeout(function () {
                    me.countDown();
                }, 10);
            } else {
                this.elem.innerHTML = this.mes;
                return;
            }
        },
        addZero: function (num) {
            return ('0' + num).slice(-2);
        }
    }

    function CDT() {

        // Set countdown limit
        var tl = new Date();

        alert(tl);

        // You can add time's up message here
        var timer = new CountdownTimer('CDT', tl, '<span class="number-wrapper"><div class="line"></div><span class="number end">Время истекло</span></span>');
        timer.countDown();
    }

    function CDT2() {

        // Set countdown limit
        var tl = new Date('2014/03/30 00:00:00');

        // You can add time's up message here
        var timer = new CountdownTimer('CDT2', tl, '<span class="number-wrapper"><div class="line"></div><span class="number end">Время истекло</span></span>');
        timer.countDown();
    }
    window.onload = function () {
        CDT();
        CDT2();
    }

    function CountdownTimer(elm, tl, mes) {
        this.initialize.apply(this, arguments);
    }

});
```

Подскажите пожалуйста как сделать так, чтобы он считал оставшееся время до конца суток? Т.е. каждый день бы обнулялся и начинал сначала 24 часа отсчитывать?

Answer (score 1):

Получить завтрашний день можно таким образом

```
var t = new Date();
    t.setDate(t.getDate() + 1);
    var tl = new Date(t.getFullYear() + '/' + (t.getMonth() + 1) + '/' + t.getDate() + ' 00:00:00');
```

Рабочий пример с вашим кодом на [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Bw5yg/) (отсчет до конца текущего дня в функции CDT())